# Find the number of three digit numbers with a even number of positive divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I guess the question is probably just asking for the number of the three digit composite numbers besides the perfect square.

So the question critical to solving the problem is really how to find those three digit prime.

Comment: It’s not asking for the number of three-digit composite numbers. $121$ is composite but has exactly $3$ positive divisors, $1,11$, and $121$.

Comment: It isn't exactly the number of composite numbers of three digits. It has to have an even number of positive divisors, so for example all the primes are here (2 divisors is an even number) also all the products of different primes, but for example a square of a prime couldn't work (like 169, which has 3 divisors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $n=p_{1}^{a_1}\cdots p_{r}^{a_r}$ has $(a_1+1)\cdots(a_r+1)$ positive divisors,

the number of positive divisors is odd iff $a_i$ is even for every $i$ iff $n$ is a perfect square; so

the number of 3-digit numbers with an even number of positive divisors should be $900-22=878$

(since the 3-digit perfect squares are $10^2, \cdots,31^2$).

Comment: This problem now seem so easy, but was otherwise when I was given this on a contest. Ughh

Comment: I know the feeling - sometimes I just don't see the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Primes are irrelevant, sorry, look at the answer above.

Square numbers will have an odd number of factors too. This can be seen by observing that if a number is a square, then all of the exponents in its prime factorization are even, so the number of factors is only the product of $1$ plus those exponents which will lead to an odd product. Therefore, the number are looking for is the number of three-digit numbers, $900$, minus the number of squares between $100$ and $999$ inclusive, $22$, minus the number of primes between $100$ and $999$, $143$, which is $735$.

Comment: How do you know there are that many primes? Without calculator just bare handed

Comment: @Doeser:  you don't have to worry about primes.  They have two factors, which is even.